# Stuck in the Ubuntu 19.10 login loop

Tags: gnome, login, xorg, 19.10

For the last few days, I’ve been working happily using Ubuntu 19.10 64 bit on my Dell Optiplex 390.  It’s been running smoothly until I used Gnome Boxes (VM software) with Windows 7 Pro.  The Optiplex froze and I gave it a while, but eventually it stopped humming and the disk read/write indicator went off.  So naturally I force restarted it by holding down the power button.  Now I’m experiencing the classic Ubuntu 19.10 login loop which so many people have struggled with- except it’s different.

I’ve looked at over a hundred different websites and followed instructions.  My `.Xauthority` file is correct, I’ve reconfigured `xorg`, etc.  The odd thing is, I can use my secondary account but not my primary account (the one I ran Boxes on and had to shut down).  I’ve also tried logging in via `CTRL + ALT + F2`, but all it gives me is a blinking cursor and no input prompt.  I’ve tried booting into recovery mode and `dpkg`-ing everything.  Still nothing.

Help with this issue is greatly appreciated, as I have a good deal of important content on this desktop and I don’t really want to reinstall.

Comment: Is there a .crash file in /var/crash?

Comment: @user535733 I don’t know, let me check.

Comment: @user535733 there are several, but none appear to be related to Xorg or any backend stuff.

Comment: Don't go by "*appear to be related,*" go by the time of the most recent crash that you experienced. Er, you do realize that a "login loop" is really a *crash*, right?

Comment: @user535733 Yep, I do realize it is a crash (I’m not a total newbie).  The crashes listed are Google Chrome, Gnome Shell, and Gnome Boxes, which is what I was using when I had to force shut down...  Possibly related?

Comment: Your title says 19.04 (EOL & thus off-topic), but question talks of 19.10. I also don't think using power-off is natural (but risky!) as you didn't mention trying to shutdown cleanly via sysrq keys or other means.   If I'd have used power-off, I'd boot a 'live' media & `fsck` (file system check to check for any errors caused by unclean shutdown & quick observation of system on disk).

Comment: @guiverc Just fixed that.  I wasn’t aware of any other shutdown method.  Fsck is my next option.

Comment: When were those crash files created, and how do those times match up against crashes you have experienced?

Comment: @user535733 They're about the same time the crashes occurred.  Some stuff has happened since I posted this question.  Long story short, I went into recovery mode and copied all of my files to a new account.  Then I deleted the old one.  Now, the new one is having the same problem.  I'm thinking of going down to an LTS release- can't wait till 20.04.